# 404 Error while loading fonts

Tags: css, fonts, path, font-face, webfonts

I've my site structure as below

```
root
|
|-- ProjectDir
    |
    |-- fonts
    |   |-- my-webfont.woff
    |
    |-- css
    |   |-- vendor
    |       |-- my-style.css
    |
    |-- rent.html
```

In **"my-style.css"** file, font is linked using a site-root-relative url

```
url('/fonts/my-webfont.woff')
```

I use a **local webserver** to view

```
http://localhost/ProjectDir/rent.html
```

But my fonts are not loading and when I try to load

```
http://localhost/fonts/my-webfont.woff
```

it shows a 404 Error (File Not Found).

You can see the my git repo here: https://github.com/abhisekp/House-Rent-Calculator and see the fonts/ directory.

And loading the font file using the web server shows 404 Error. See here: https://abhisekp.github.io/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot

What's wrong with all this? My local server also behaves this way.

Comment: tried `url('fonts/my-webfont.woff')`? (without the leading /)

Comment: @boris That would look for the fonts in `vendor`,

Comment: @Matt that would look for the fonts in `css`

Comment: It works fine on my computer. Are all the fonts failing or only one in particular? Maybe your server is not configured to serve some file extensions

Comment: The directory structure in the question I asked is wrong. I apologize. But the git repo is the exact project I asked about. *Use it for reference.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I found the bug.

Actually, the problem was the root itself. When viewing using **https://abhisekp.github.io/House-Rent-Calculator** address, the root is **"abhisekp.github.io/"** not **"abhisekp.github.io/House-Rent-Calculator/"** hence the **@font-face urls** refer to the former rather than the later.

The fonts lies under **"House-Rent-Calculator/"** directory. I fixed it by using a relative link (*safe for everything if "fonts/" & "css/" directories are not changed frequently*).

**No more root-relative links** as I test using various servers and my **"House-Rent-Calculator/"** directory might be anywhere in the server.

> Better be safe than sorry! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

`url('../../fonts/my-webfont.woff');`

Comment: Correct relative link: url('../fonts/my-webfont.woff'); <-- this works